# Wordpress plugin get version. Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: wordpress

I want to make a plugin for all of my own wordpress-based websites.
The idea is simple, I want to get the version (and probably another info) of those sites by using CURL.
Right now, I have such a code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Manage Site
Plugin URI: http://not-available-yet.com/
Description: A manage site plugin
Author: Go Frendi Gunawan
Version: 0.0
Author URI: http://not-available-yet.com/
*/

// this file is located on wp-content/plugins/manage_site

require_once '../../../wp-includes/version.php'; // do I need to include everything manually like this?


if(isset($_GET['key']))
{
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    if($key=='1234'){
        echo $wp_version;
    }
}
```

And I can access it by using CURL with this address:
http://my_domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/manage_site/manage_site.php?key=1234

And I'll get the wordpress version as a response:

> 3.5.1

It is work for now.

But, since this is my first time writing a wordpress plugin, I might do things wrongly. So, Am I doing it right? Or is there any better way to write this?

Comment: I guess doing "global $wp_version" (not having to require the version file) and "echo $wp_version" will suffice.

Comment: Your plugin is already in WordPress ecosystem, you don't need to `include` nothing (only in rare, special cases). You may like this [Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/85486/12615). ::: I guess that if you join this and @kjetilh comments you already have an Answer ;)

Comment: Ok, How should I exactly do "global $wp_version". I found that "version.php" is not included by default that's why I include it manually. Do I need something else to be set, so that I don't need to include everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.
Both, @kjetilh and @brasofilo was right in case of accessing wordpress plugin "the normal way".
Since I access the plugin directly, the wordpress bootstrap is not loaded. Therefore, my first approach was partially right.
But load the wp-load.php is more elegant (and simple and usable) since it load everything, not only the version, and it gonna be useful to access 'more information':

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Manage Site
Plugin URI: http://not-available-yet.com/
Description: A manage site plugin
Author: Go Frendi Gunawan
Version: 0.0
Author URI: http://not-available-yet.com/
*/

// this file is located on wp-content/plugins/manage_site

require_once '../../../wp-load.php';

if(isset($_GET['key']))
{
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    if($key=='1234'){
        echo $wp_version;
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case it's not really a plugin it's just a stand-alone file. It seems it works for you though so no big harm.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I might don't have a "clear" definition of "plugin" in wordpress :p